# a single regression for all of the points in a superposed xyplot (lattice)

Tags: r, regression, lattice

I have this code, and I want plot a single regression line for all the groups in the plot (not one regression for each group).

How can I do that? (I have 3 groups of furrows)

This is my code:

```
VOL<-xyplot(B$Inflow.Vol..During.Adv...m.3.~B$c..cm.|factor(dat$Group),

scales=list(alternating=1, tck = c(1,0)),

groups = B$Furrow,

par.settings = list (superpose.line = list (lty = c(1, 2, 4) , lwd = lin2), superpose.symbol = list (pch = symbols)),

auto.key = list (text = c("Furrow 1", "Furrow 3", "Furrow 5"),rows = 3, corner = c(0.95, 0.6), lines = FALSE , points = TRUE, title = ""),

type = c("p","r"), cex = mycex2, grid=TRUE, xlab = "C", ylab = "Inflow Volume During Advance, m3")
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You did not provide data. You should provide data.

Here is an example using the `iris` data set.

`xyplot(Sepal.Length~Petal.Length|cut(Sepal.Width,3),iris,
       groups=Species,
       panel=function(x,y,...){
         l=lm(y~x)
         panel.xyplot(x,y,...)
         panel.abline(l)
       })`

Within the `panel` function, calculate the regression line for each panel, then plot the data and the fit line.